# Pass TIME object via bundle

Tags: android, datetime, android-intent, bundle

How to pass an instance (object) of TIME using a Bundle???

May be a simple question,but i need a precise answer...

```
DATE date=new DATE();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code is approximate since I am writing it from memory .

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
mIntent.putLong(KEY, getTimeMilliseconds());
startactivity(mIntent);
```

Then in the onCreate of ActivityB :

```
Bundle mBundle = getItent().getExtras();
Long time = mBundle.getLong(KEY);
```

Note :

> putLong / getLong can apply to multiple type String , int ...
>
> If you want it to apply to a custom object you should make that object
> implement Parcelable.

Comment: I need to pass to another class,but not an Activity...can anybody please be specific???

Comment: You need your object to implement parcelable [Parcelable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8653518/794291) . Once your object does that you can use bundle to transfer it .

Answer (score 22):

Dates are serializable, so you can use `get/putSerializable`:

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable(MyFragment.DATE_KEY, new Date());
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

In `MyFragment`:

```
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState : getArguments();
    Date startTime = (Date) bundle.getSerializable(MyFragment.DATE_KEY);
    this.time = startTime;
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    bundle.putSerializable(MyFragment.DATE_KEY, this.time);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the long value which represents your date in the Bundle e.g. long time = new Date().getTime();