# how to parse my arraylist value one activity to another activity?

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

Hi I have created one fully xml based project. my doubts now I store all xml value in my array list. The array list name is mspec_List. how to parse this array list value? I got all values using sax parser. my 1st activity display some images if i click that images i want to show some paragraph in my next activity screen that paragraph are stored in my array list. how to show that paragraph in my next activity? I have created new class and i am using an textview, also i wish to show that array list value in that textview. please help me....`

i am trying to parse that arraylist value but it's not working see the below code.

```
    sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ParxmlActivity.this, tabview.class);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("numbers", mspec_List);
            //intent.putExtra("name",model_List.get(position).name);


            startActivity(intent);  

        }
    });
```

full source code:

```
  package ml.ml;

    import java.io.IOException; 
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
    import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.AssetManager;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

    public class ParxmlActivity extends Activity {

        private String array_spinner[];
        private Cursor cursor;
        private int columnIndex;

        ParsedExampleDataSet parsedExampleDataSet= null;

        ArrayList<String> hltag_List=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Subchild>sltag_List=new ArrayList<Subchild>();

        ArrayList<String> name_List =new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> path_List =new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> mmimage_List = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> mname_List = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> mmimage = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> mvideo_List = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<schild> model_List =new ArrayList<schild>();
        ArrayList<String> mspec_List = new ArrayList<String>();

        Spinner spinner_hltag,spinner_sltag, spinner_path;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_hltag;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_sltag;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_path;

        int hltagPos=0;
        int sltagPos=0;


        Object sdcard;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
            spinner_hltag= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            spinner_sltag = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

            sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


                public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ParxmlActivity.this, tabview.class);
                    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("numbers", mspec_List);
                    //intent.putExtra("name",model_List.get(position).name);


                    startActivity(intent);  

                }
            });

            sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};

            cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    proj, null, null, null);


            columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);



            try {
                /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

                /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

                /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader */
                ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

                /* Parse the xml-data from our file. */
                xr.parse(new InputSource(getAssets().open("mafile.xml")));
                /* Parsing has finished. */

                parsedExampleDataSet =myExampleHandler. myParsedExampleDataSet;

                for (int i = 0; i < parsedExampleDataSet.gethltag().size(); i++) {
                    Log.v("gethltag SIZE ", ""+parsedExampleDataSet.gethltag().size());
                    hltag_List.add(parsedExampleDataSet.getHLTag().get(i));

                }

                sltag_List = parsedExampleDataSet.getSLTag(hltag_List.get(hltagPos));


                for(int i = 0; i < sltag_List.size(); i++) {
                    name_List.add(sltag_List.get(i).name);
                    path_List.add(sltag_List.get(i).path);



                }
                    model_List.clear();     
                    model_List = sltag_List.get(sltagPos).model;

                    for(int j = 0; j<model_List.size(); j++){
                        mmimage_List.addAll(model_List.get(j).imageList);
                        mname_List.add(model_List.get(j).name);
                        mvideo_List.addAll(model_List.get(j).videoList);
                        mmimage.add(model_List.get(j).mimage);
                        mspec_List.add(model_List.get(j).spec);

                    }



                spinner_hltag.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(ParxmlActivity.this, R.layout.row, hltag_List)); 


                spinner_sltag.setAdapter(new MyAdapter1(ParxmlActivity.this, R.layout.row1,name_List)); 




            } catch (Exception e) { 

            }


        }


        private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private Context mContext;
            //ArrayList<String> path_List =new ArrayList<String>();

            public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
                mContext = c;
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return path_List.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView imageView;
                if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                } else {
                    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
                }

                //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_List);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_List.get(position));
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                return imageView;

            }



        }
        public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{


            public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   ArrayList<String> hltagList) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, hltagList);
            }



            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
                return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
            }

            public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
                View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

                TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.weekofday);
                label.setText(hltag_List.get(position));



                ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_List.get(position));;
                icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                return row;
            }
        }

        public class MyAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<String>{


            public MyAdapter1(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   ArrayList<String> name_List) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, name_List);
            }



            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
                return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
            }

            public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
                View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

                TextView sub=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.weekofday1);
                sub.setText(name_List.get(position));

                ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_List.get(position));;
                icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                return row;
            }
        }

    }
```

`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing ArrayLists in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653462/passing-arraylists-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are having String ArrayList you can simply pass it using `intent.putStringArrayListExtra(name, value)`. For more you can check my answer [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653462/passing-arraylists-in-android/8654114#8654114).

Comment: intent.putStringArrayListExtra("numbers", mspec_List); this is right

Comment: ok lalit poptani after what can i do? now i parsed string value one activity to another activity i am using tab view also 3tabview? the i wish to show my text view in my 1st tab view screen so i add one text view in my xml file after what can i do? teach me....this is my tabview full source code link 1. http://paste.org/44196 2. http://paste.org/44195

Answer (score 1):

tabview.class

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
arrlist = i.getStringArrayListExtra("name");
```

Comment: lntathep please see my code this my tabview.class source code: http://paste.org/44196 i have 3 tabview i wish to show this arraylist value in my 1st tabview that tabview source code link: http://paste.org/44195 please help me i am confused this concept

Comment: what is the use of parcelable?

Answer (score 0):

You can make model_List static.

Comment: my model_List dynamic degratnik